# To extract the specific strings from the given string in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

expression  - `BR65437812-909@-@BR12340000-990`

Need to extract the given expression and update in columns like 
`a = BR12340000`, `b = 990`

Comment: So, everything before the first hyphen and everything after the last hyphen?

Comment: I want data in between @ and last hyphen in the first column

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
  SUBSTR(s, 1, INSTR(s, '-') - 1) as a, 
  SUBSTR(s, INSTR(s, '-', -1) + 1) as b 
from 
  (select 'BR65437812-909@-@BR12340000-990' as s from dual)
```

Using `SUBSTR(string, start, length)` we have the following arguments:

For A:

- the string to search
- 1 as the `start` and
- (index_of_the_first_hyphen - 1) as the `length`. `INSTR(string, searchfor)` gives us the index of the first hyphen

For B:

Using `SUBSTR(string, start)` we have arguments:

- the string to search
- the (index_of_last_hyphen + 1) - this time we use the extra  `INSTR(string, searchfor, startindex)` argument `startindex` and set it to -1; this makes it search from the end of the string and work backwards, giving us the index of the last hyphen

We don't need a length argument - SUBSTR without length returns the rest of the string to the end

It's important to note that INSTR with a start index of -1 does search backwards but it always returns the index from the start of the string, not the end.

```
INSTR('dddde', 'd', -1)  
       12345            -- returns 4, because d is 4 from the start
       54321            -- it does not return 2, even though d is 2 from the "start" when searching backwards
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with s as (
select 'BR65437812-909@-@BR12340000-990' str from dual)
select regexp_substr(str, '[^-@]+', 1, 3) a, regexp_substr(str, '[^-@]+', 1, 4) b
from s;

A          B  
---------- ---
BR12340000 990
```

Comment: What portion of this is needed to be explain?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_replace` to get every character after last `@`sign firstly, and then split by dash.

```
with t(str) as
(
select regexp_replace('BR65437812-909@-@BR12340000-990','.*@','') from dual
) 
select regexp_replace(str,'-.*','') as a,
       regexp_replace(str,'.*-','') as b
  from t;

A           B
----------  ---
BR12340000  990
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/NWU56252)</kbd>